# What happens if a dry charged battery is used without electrolyte?

Tags: battery, scooter

I bought a battery today for my scooter. The mechanic fitted the battery into the scooter and it seems to be running fine. But when I noticed the battery's box later on, it said "Dry Charged" and on further reading in the manual, I figured out that the battery would have needed some sort of "electrolyte" and also an "initial charging before it could be used.

I went back and enquired in the battery shop about it, and he said it's not needed - that I could use it without any initial steps. But I'm worried..

If I continue to use it in this "Dry" state, what would happen?

Thanks,

Pradyumna

Comment: Did you check to see if the battery was filled? The electrolyte allows the battery to conduct electricity. It probably wouldn't work without any in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you'll have any issues. If you continue to be worried about it, you should be able to pull the caps off of the top of the battery to check the fluid level within. You should be able to see the electrolyte at almost the top. If you don't, then I would take it back to the shop where you had it fitted and get them involved in getting it up to snuff. As Nick suggested, if it were actually "dry" (without electrolyte), there wouldn't be any electricity produced and your scooter would not start to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

My grandson installed a dry charged 6v battery in his Honda CT 90 6 months ago. The electrolyte remained in the box never added and eventualy discarded when the box was destroyed by leaking acid.
The battery worked all summer and was showing 6.8 v when the bike failed to start this October.
When I discovered it dry,I added tap water..only slight drop in voltage but the hi beam still worked. Go figure.
The plates looked a bit white. 
Could be the dealer HAD added electrolyte and the questionable rectifier boiled it away...still it did run fine up until now with 0 in the bat.
Will go NEW battery and replacment Radio Shack rectifier. Hopfully no more mystery surprises.
R